# Maximum update depth exceeded new state React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

const [number,setNum] = useState(0); I get this error when I want to add and change it(setNum(number+1)). My Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. What can i to solve this?

```js
const App = ()=>{
  const [text,setText] = useState('');
  const [todo,setToDo] = useState([]);
  const [number,setNum] = useState(0);
  const renderToDoCard = ({item})=>{
    setNum(number+1)
    return(
    <TouchableHighlight
      onLongPress={() => handleLongPress(item)}>
      <ToDoCard todo={item} number={number}/>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )
  }
  const handleLongPress = item => {
    setToDo(todo.filter(i => i !== item));
    return Alert.alert('Silindi');
  };
  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor='#102027'/>
      <View style={styles.head_container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Yapılacaklar</Text>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{todo.length}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.body_container}>
        <FlatList data={todo} renderItem={renderToDoCard} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottom_container}>
        <ToDoInput todo={todo} setToDo={setToDo} text={text} setText={setText}/>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an infinite update loop.

The problem is in how you're updating your `number` state inside `renderToDoCard`

```
const renderToDoCard = ({item}) => {
  setNum(number + 1); // This is the problem, remove this line
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onLongPress={() => handleLongPress(item)}>
      <ToDoCard todo={item} number={number} />
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
};
```

When `renderToDoCard` renders you update the state of your `App` component so it rerenders `App` which renders `renderToDoCard` which updates the state of your `App` component so it rerenders `App` which renders `renderToDoCard`...

This process repeats until the max update depth is reached.

Simply remove `setNum(number + 1);` and that problem is fixed.

It seems to me from your code that all you use your `number` state for is to keep track of the current item index so you can pass this to the `ToDoCard` component. The `FlatList`'s `renderItem` also provides access to the current item index which you could pass to the number prop of `ToDoCard`

> renderItem({ item, index, separators });

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem

So you could instead do something like this

```
const renderToDoCard = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onLongPress={() => handleLongPress(item)}>
      <ToDoCard todo={item} number={index} />
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
};
```

Alternative you can add a key to each item in `todo` and use that instead of the index.